# Hotkeys ignored w Python libvlc bindings on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, libvlc

I have problem controlling videos from Python 3.x using python-vlc bindings on Linux.
The video plays fine in a window, but hotkeys seem to be ignored. Does libvlc media player handle hotkeys?

My minimal code:

```
import vlc
from time import sleep


player = vlc.MediaPlayer("test.mp4")
player.video_set_key_input(True)
player.play()
while player.get_state()!=vlc.State.Ended:
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: In short: No! Look up the built-in player at the bottom of the code in vlc.py, specifically the `keybindings` dictionary and note the `import` / definition of `getch`. The other option is to wrap you code in a GUI and handle key input there.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony So video_set_key_input() is just a deception then. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Obviously, if you know better: A) Why ask the question and B) Why not post an answer showing others, with a similar problem, how it can be solved. SO is not a competition, people post answers and comments to the best of their knowledge.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I haven't found the answer yet. Docstring for video_set_key_input() states: " By default and for historical reasons, keyboard events are handled by the LibVLC video widget." However is seems not the case.

Answer (score 1):

It is my belief that your contention, that `video_set_key_input` and `video_set_mouse_input` are the solution is a misunderstanding of those functions.

From `vlc.py`

```
def video_set_key_input(self, on):
    '''Enable or disable key press events handling, according to the LibVLC hotkeys
    configuration. By default and for historical reasons, keyboard events are
    handled by the LibVLC video widget.
    @note: On X11, there can be only one subscriber for key press and mouse
    click events per window. If your application has subscribed to those events
    for the X window ID of the video widget, then LibVLC will not be able to
    handle key presses and mouse clicks in any case.
    @warning: This function is only implemented for X11 and Win32 at the moment.
    @param on: true to handle key press events, false to ignore them.
    '''
    return libvlc_video_set_key_input(self, on)


def video_set_mouse_input(self, on):
    '''Enable or disable mouse click events handling. By default, those events are
    handled. This is needed for DVD menus to work, as well as a few video
    filters such as "puzzle".
    See L{video_set_key_input}().
    @warning: This function is only implemented for X11 and Win32 at the moment.
    @param on: true to handle mouse click events, false to ignore them.
    '''
    return libvlc_video_set_mouse_input(self, on)
```

This suggests that setting those functions to `False` simply tells `vlc` that mouse and key input are to be ignored and passed to the users appliction.
For that to work, your application must be accepting and processing, mouse and key input coming out of the assigned X-window.

Not, that suddenly, pressing the space bar will pause the video, as when, vlc is performing the task of `accepting and processing` the mouse and key input.